# How can I inject different instance with Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

For example, Let say like below.

- there is a Activity named MyActivity.
- there are two class named A, B and MyActivity has these class instances.
- there is a class named C that I want to inject into A & B.
- C has a scope that follows activity lifecycle.

In this situation, regardless of the scope, Is there any way of passing a different instance of C into A, B with Dagger 2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40447384/7045114

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide objects of the same type? Dagger2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447262/how-to-provide-objects-of-the-same-type-dagger2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html). From the qualifiers section of the [dagger user's guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html):

> Sometimes the type alone is insufficient to identify a dependency. In
>   this case, we add a qualifier annotation.

For your case, mere `C` is not enough to identify the two different dependencies you want injected into `A` and `B`. So you would add a qualifier to distinguish the two instances. Here is an example:

```
public class A {

    private final C c;

    @Inject
    public A(@Named("Instance 1") C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public class B {
    private final C c;

    @Inject 
    public B(@Named("Instance 2") C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Module:

```
@Module
public class CModule() {

    @Provides
    @Named("Instance 1")
    C provideInstance1OfC() {
        return new C();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("Instance 2")
    C provideInstance2OfC() {
        return new C();
    }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component( modules = { CModule.class } )
public interface ActivityComponent {
    void inject(MyActivitiy activity);
}
```

Then finally:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Inject A a;
    @Inject B b;

    @Override
    void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
             .cModule(new CModule())
             .build()
             .inject(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, why i couldn't ever think of this way? you are saint. Thanks.