# Does the night mode need sqlite?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-night-mode

I just want to know if the night mode in Android needs sqlite?
or there's another way to save the mode in it
when the user close the app and reopen it again it will save the mode
pls help

If there's another way please share it with me
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sqlite is not needed.

Local application settings such as night mode preference are typically stored in [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Answer (score 1):

You can just save a variable in the SharedPreferences of the app for the preferred user settings and set theme on launch.
Go through the documentation to know more .[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Comment: Rule of thumb - provide a link rather than the "Go through the documentation". Have a happy contributing!

Answer (score 1):

Please, check [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). This is key-value storage and it's exactly suited for such needs.

As general practice - create some SharedPrefManager and move all logic with shared preferences there. Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19613702/4714510).

Answer (score 1):

Write this code on the first page that runs

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("nightMode", 0);
    if(pref.getBoolean("mode",false)){
        // code change ui to night
    }
```

and Write this code on the night mode switch

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("nightMode", 0);

    pref.edit().putBoolean("mode",true).apply();
```

Just as easily