# How to use a String stored in sharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-studio-4.2

I have this two methods "saveCurrentPlayer" and "loadCurrentPlayer" in a class "PlayersActivity" to save and load a String.

```
public void saveCurrentPlayer(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("currentPlayer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("currentPlayer",jugadorEliminar);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String loadCurrentPlayer(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("currentPlayer",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String currentPlayer = preferences.getString("currentPlayer","");
        return currentPlayer;
    }
```

I try to get that String "currentPlayer" from another class "QuestionAnswerManagerActivity" but I get force close.

```
Toast.makeText(QuestionAnswerManagerActivity.this,playersActivity.loadCurrentPlayer(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here the logcat:

```
2021-06-29 19:00:25.584 12936-12936/? I/actual.pregres: type=1400 audit(0.0:9796): avc: denied { sendto } for path="/dev/socket/logdw" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_dgram_socket permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:25.668 12936-12936/? I/zygote: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-06-29 19:00:28.285 12936-12936/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-06-29 19:00:28.696 12936-12936/? I/JDWP: type=1400 audit(0.0:9801): avc: denied { connectto } for path=006A6477702D636F6E74726F6C scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:28.840 12936-12936/? I/JDWP: type=1400 audit(0.0:9802): avc: denied { read write } for path="socket:[145879]" dev="sockfs" ino=145879 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:31.308 12936-12936/? I/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:9807): avc: denied { write } for path="socket:[145879]" dev="sockfs" ino=145879 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:34.828 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/com.doctoractual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9828): avc: denied { write } for comm=45474C20496E6974 name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=174 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:34.844 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/com.doctoractual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9830): avc: denied { connectto } for comm=45474C20496E6974 path="/dev/socket/property_service" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:35.071 12936-12962/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from the current namespace instead.
2021-06-29 19:00:35.231 12936-12962/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so from the current namespace instead.
2021-06-29 19:00:35.639 12936-12962/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so from the current namespace instead.
2021-06-29 19:00:35.672 12936-12962/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so from the current namespace instead.
2021-06-29 19:00:36.080 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/actual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9835): avc: denied { write } for name="BASE_DATOS" dev="sdb3" ino=81843 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:36.080 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/actual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9836): avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/com.doctoractual.pregresp/databases/BASE_DATOS" dev="sdb3" ino=81843 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:36.120 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/actual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9837): avc: denied { lock } for path="/data/data/com.doctoractual.pregresp/databases/BASE_DATOS" dev="sdb3" ino=81843 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:36.173 12936-12970/com.doctoractual.pregresp D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2021-06-29 19:00:36.222 12936-12947/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 4602(981KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 66% free, 780KB/2MB, paused 8.318ms total 54.936ms
2021-06-29 19:00:36.492 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:9844): avc: denied { write } for name="local_opengl" dev="tmpfs" ino=14777 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:socket_device:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:36.643 12936-12970/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-06-29 19:00:36.643 12936-12970/com.doctoractual.pregresp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2021-06-29 19:00:36.647 12936-12970/com.doctoractual.pregresp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2021-06-29 19:00:36.647 12936-12970/com.doctoractual.pregresp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2021-06-29 19:00:36.677 12936-12970/com.doctoractual.pregresp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe7a051e0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
2021-06-29 19:00:36.760 12936-12970/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.vbox86.so from the current namespace instead.
2021-06-29 19:00:36.778 12936-12970/com.doctoractual.pregresp E/eglCodecCommon: goldfish_dma_create_region: could not obtain fd to device! fd -1 errno=2
2021-06-29 19:00:37.177 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-06-29 19:00:38.704 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/actual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9870): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=136 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:38.704 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/actual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9871): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=136 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:41.640 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager
2021-06-29 19:00:41.642 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/IntentService
2021-06-29 19:00:41.643 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock
2021-06-29 19:00:41.649 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/Instrumentation
2021-06-29 19:00:41.650 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/JobSchedulerImpl
2021-06-29 19:00:41.651 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/job/JobServiceEngine$JobHandler
2021-06-29 19:00:41.663 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/ActivityThread
2021-06-29 19:00:41.666 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/Debug
2021-06-29 19:00:41.667 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager
2021-06-29 19:00:41.668 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/job/JobService
2021-06-29 19:00:41.669 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/PendingIntent
2021-06-29 19:00:41.673 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/location/LocationManager
2021-06-29 19:00:41.675 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: java/net/URL
2021-06-29 19:00:41.684 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp W/com.doctoractual.pregresp: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2021-06-29 19:00:41.687 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/chatty: uid=10071(u0_a71) com.doctoractual.pregresp identical 11 lines
2021-06-29 19:00:41.688 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp W/com.doctoractual.pregresp: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2021-06-29 19:00:42.597 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp W/zygote: Verification of void android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopBinderTrackingAndDump(android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor) took 108.552ms
2021-06-29 19:00:42.911 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper
2021-06-29 19:00:42.912 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp W/com.doctoractual.pregresp: Changing class Landroid/app/AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper;
2021-06-29 19:00:42.914 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp W/com.doctoractual.pregresp: Dex file created by class-definition time transformation of Landroid/app/AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper; is not checked for all retransformation invariants.
2021-06-29 19:00:43.072 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper
2021-06-29 19:00:43.074 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp W/zygote: Verification of void android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(int, long, long, long, int, android.app.PendingIntent, android.app.AlarmManager$OnAlarmListener, java.lang.String, android.os.Handler, android.os.WorkSource, android.app.AlarmManager$AlarmClockInfo) took 321.983ms
2021-06-29 19:00:43.118 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/location/LocationManager$ListenerTransport
2021-06-29 19:00:43.119 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp W/com.doctoractual.pregresp: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2021-06-29 19:00:43.202 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp W/zygote: Verification of void android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(android.location.LocationRequest, android.location.LocationListener, android.os.Looper, android.app.PendingIntent) took 123.589ms
2021-06-29 19:00:43.234 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Profiler initialization complete on agent.
2021-06-29 19:00:43.250 12936-13005/com.doctoractual.pregresp V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events
2021-06-29 19:00:43.535 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=26KB
2021-06-29 19:00:43.536 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=26KB
2021-06-29 19:00:43.536 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2021-06-29 19:00:45.193 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=45KB, data=44KB
2021-06-29 19:00:45.195 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=45KB, data=44KB
2021-06-29 19:00:45.205 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
2021-06-29 19:00:45.238 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2021-06-29 19:00:45.238 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2021-06-29 19:00:45.582 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=66KB
2021-06-29 19:00:45.588 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=107KB, data=42KB
2021-06-29 19:00:50.239 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=76KB
2021-06-29 19:00:50.236 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/com.doctoractual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9879): avc: denied { sendto } for comm=4A69742074687265616420706F6F6C path="/dev/socket/logdw" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_dgram_socket permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:00:50.250 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=76KB
2021-06-29 19:00:50.250 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
2021-06-29 19:00:50.340 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/Choreographer: Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-06-29 19:00:50.733 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: JIT allocated 56KB for compiled code of void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2021-06-29 19:00:50.932 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=244KB, data=143KB
2021-06-29 19:00:50.933 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=238KB, data=98KB
2021-06-29 19:00:52.121 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=243KB, data=108KB
2021-06-29 19:00:52.123 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=243KB, data=108KB
2021-06-29 19:00:52.130 12936-12941/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
2021-06-29 19:01:01.116 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/actual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9884): avc: denied { read } for name="databases" dev="sdb3" ino=81729 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:01:01.116 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp I/actual.pregresp: type=1400 audit(0.0:9885): avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/com.doctoractual.pregresp/databases" dev="sdb3" ino=81729 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=1
2021-06-29 19:01:01.142 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-29 19:01:01.144 12936-12936/com.doctoractual.pregresp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.doctoractual.pregresp, PID: 12936
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.doctoractual.pregresp.PlayersActivity.loadCurrentPlayer()' on a null object reference
        at com.doctoractual.pregresp.QuestionAnswerManagerActivity$4.onClick(QuestionAnswerManagerActivity.java:216)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

But writing a text directly there is no problem, everything works.

```
Toast.makeText(QuestionAnswerManagerActivity.this,"Jugador Luis",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Someone can see what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you call the playersActivity.loadCurrentPlayer() in ```QuestionAnswerManagerActivity```, the ```playersActivity``` may have been null. So a better way is to extract the ```loadCurrentPlayer``` out from ```playersActivity``` into a static helper method. Call it by providing the current activity as context. For example ```Helper.loadCurrentPlayer(context)```

Comment: @HarryQ Thanks a lot for your answering quickly. It helped me to solve the problem. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **dependent** on some other activity in order to use `SharedPreferences`. In this case, `playersActivity` is `null` when you have tried to use it. This is a very bad Android development design as you do not need `SharedPreferences` to have any dependencies, it can be fully independent.

**Solution: 3 Options**

1. Turn your `SharedPreferences` in to `Static` Methods. (ex. `loadCurrentPlayer` in `playersActivity` should be `Static`)
2. **Best Practice**: Create a new Manager class that is responsible for app's entire `SharedPreferences` usage (ex. `SharedPreferenceManager`). This class is a `Singleton` Class that is instantiated with `ApplicationContext` and has all the methods related CRUD operations in `SharedPreferences`, in your case `saveCurrentPlayer` and  `loadCurrentPlayer`. Since the manager class is independent, it should not cause any `Lifecycle` errors or `NullPointer` errors.

   Since attaching sample code will clutter my answer, I decided to cite [someone else's code here, this will teach you how to implement it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347393/12301279)
3. **If you are too lazy to follow #2**: You can use a library that has done that for you already: [Pixplicity/EasyPrefs](https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPrefs).

   - Easy to use like `Manager` Class ✅
   - No more errors related to `SharedPreferences` ✅
   - You could always retrofit into any existing project ✅

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great and very complete answer. It solved it my problem and it helped me to learn and continue improving my little knowledge. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure no problem. I always strive for the best practices and I like to share them as well. I am glad it helped you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line in both of your methods,

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("currentPlayer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Add this in your MainActivity class (outside methods)

```
public static SharedPreferences preferences ;
```

Now add this in your MainActivity OnCreate method :

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences("currentPlayer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This solved the issue in my case...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answering. It helped me to solve the problem. I appreciate it.